# Fusion table styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I am importing data from fusion table data as a layer. but the colour i used in fusion tables is not reflected in my map. it by default remains red small icon.
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.
   layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query: {
   select: 'geometry',
   from: '1f1XfTx7J52PZJv3mwnBq3rCiPwb6x1li67ca6lg'
   }
   });

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes fusion tables will cache a previous style, and it will take some time for changes to be reflected.

You could try [setting the style explicitly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling) in the API.

Comment: It has not changed still. Two days back same code worked fine but now it's not. Do I need to add style to fusion table layer.